# How to display phone numbers in SQL that contain two and only two '0s'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that will extract phone numbers from a column that are formatted in a particular manner. This format is causing me to run into some problems on how to extract the numbers I need.

Some context: I have a table called Suppliers and a column called Phone. An example phone number would be: (010) 9984510. The area codes are all enclosed in parentheses. There are several phone numbers in the column with a similar format. I need to extract the phone numbers that contain two AND ONLY two '0s' in them. Here is what I tried:

```
select SupplierID, Phone
from Suppliers
where Phone like '%0%0%';
```

SupplierID is just a column with an ID number. The main problem I am facing is how can I extract those numbers with two and only two '0s'? The parentheses are causing me to extract more numbers than needed. I do not believe I am allowed to edit the column in any way, but any solution is welcome.

Comment: `(010) 9984510` contains three zeroes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `like` and `not like`:

```
where Phone like '%0%0%' and Phone not like '%0%0%0%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `replace()` and `len()`:

```
where len(phone) - len(replace(phone, '0', '')) = 2
```

Comment: That actually worked very well. The hint I had suggested using two like operators, but I was able to achieve the correct amount of output. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Answer (score 1):

For "giggles", you could take a very different approach and count the `0` characters:

```
SELECT YT.*
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(V.C) AS Zeroes
                  FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15))T(I) --I doubt a phone number will be over 15 characters long
                       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(YT.Phone,T.I,1)))V(C)
                  WHERE V.C = '0') Z
WHERE Z.Zeroes = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the area code

```
where phone like '%)%0%0%' and phone not like '%)%0%0%0%'
```